# Chrome extension for highlight+find prepopulate?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, find, google-chrome-extensions

I switched from Firefox to Chrome as my go-to browser some months ago and there is one piece of functionality that still pesters me. Seems trivial/ignorable but this one is driving me nuts little by little...

I like to be able to highlight text, click CTRL-F, and have the find dialogue come up with the highlighted text prepopulated. Chrome (14.0.+) just shows my last search prepopulated. Is there any extension to help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Windows you can use the following Autohotkey script:

```
#SingleInstance force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#IfWinActive ,Chrome
^f::Send ^c^f^v^a
```

When pressing Ctrl+F this hotkeys sends Ctrl+C, Ctrl+F, Ctrl+V and Ctrl+A
So it copies, search, paste and select all the copied text in the search box.

I guess something better could be done, checking the clipboard, but that's out of my Autohotkey knowledge :P

I have [uploaded a compiled script](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3682061/SuperUser/prepopulate_search_ctrl_f.exe) if you don't have Autohotkey

Comment: Terrible idea... I don't want Ctrl-F to change the content of my clipboard!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that its possible, your best bet would be to use

```
Ctrl-C then Ctrl-F then Ctrl-V
```

Theres also Google Quickscroll that will show you that'll let you jump to a relevant paragraph from a google search [Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/okanipcmceoeemlbjnmnbdibhgpbllgc)