# How to find a word only in selected text?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, find, browser-addons

I usually use Chrome browser and I'd like to know how can I find a specific word only in selected text, not in all webpage when pressing Ctrl+F. How can I do it? You can suggest any other browsers if Chrome can't do this. Thanks.

Comment: In firefox you can select text, right-click, chose View Selection Source from the menu, and then press Ctrl + F to search.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/268667/is-there-any-way-of-making-ctrlf-in-chrome-use-the-selected-text-as-per-firefo

Comment: @Gantendo Thanks, I think Firefox is more suitable for this. Perfect would be if I select the text and it would find a word in selected text instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to select text, print and save to pdf.
Maybe there is way to do it via python to extract style of bootstap page and add it html file to but I experienced faulty libraries while I tried to. Find+ should have list search matches instead showing number.